# Rigify right panel duplication

Tags: animation, rigify

I have been doing some weight painting and animation using rigify, after some use the 3D view right panel controls started duplicating.
Does anyone knows how to get rid of these panels?

[image: rigify right panel control]

Comment: Are the panels still there, when reopening Blender? What action causes the creation of another duplicate? Upload your file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ .

Comment: Are there multiple "rig_ui.py" texts in the text editor?  Does each panel work on the current rig?, or have you generated multiple rigs?.. each generated rig has a unique rig_id (visible under custom properties), which is also used to reference each generated rig to panel.